# What is the right procedure to set a nonce in the csp policy?

Tags: javascript, express, xss, content-security-policy

I am trying to set a nonce in the csp policy, but it is not working as expected.

The following code is what I am currently using for testing purposes:

server.js

```
  express.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.set({
      "Content-Security-Policy":"script-src 'self' 'nonce-random1'"
    });
    return next();
  });
```

index.html

```
  <script nonce="random1" type="text/javascript" src="/script1.js"> 
  </script>
```

I am getting this error in the browser's console:
**Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-random1'...**

I tried adding the source /script1.js as if it was a domain for testing purposes:

```
  express.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.set({
      "Content-Security-Policy":"script-src 'self' /script1.js"
    });
    return next();
  });
```

Obviously it is not working and I get the same error.

I tried looking in the docs and the syntax should be correct. I tried looking at similar questions or articles related but I haven't found anything helpful.

I want to avoid using unsafe-inline.
In the future I'll implement a one time hash as nonce for every request.

Someone knows why nonce is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Refused to execute **inline event handler**

means that you have event handler buil-in tag like `<div onclick='handler()'>` or `<body onload='some_javascript_here'>` etc.
Your `<script nonce='random1'>...</script>` is executed, you can insert into it `console.log('I am done')` to ensure that.

Replace inline event handlers by [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or use jQuery for that if suitable.

> "Content-Security-Policy":"script-src 'self' /script1.js"

is [wrong](http://csplite.com/csp/check/?pl=eJxLtDK2qi4GEkppmRVK1n7WxVamVko5qWWpOUrWmVZG1mA55%2BAAJSDLyNJKqTi5KLOgRLe4KFlBvTg1J01dQR8iZKiXVaxkXQsA1oUYvw%3D%3D#result), `/script1.js` relative URLs is not allowed in the directive.
Your first CSP  `"Content-Security-Policy":"script-src 'self' 'nonce-random1'"` is correct.

Comment: This is correct, I totally ignored the first part of the error. Now it works like a charm. Thank you!